# How to show trendline in plot Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, plotly

So, i have dataset with number and datetime

[image]

And i want to visualize this data and add trendline

[image]

But don`t know how to add trendline it on plot

For visualization using plotly.

my code

```
    fig = go.Figure()
#fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_wl_1['timestamp_(utc+5)'], y=df_wl_1['water_level_(m)_-_sensor1'],
#                    mode='lines',
#                    name='Water level 1'))
#fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['parameter_type'], y=df['wind_speed'],
#                    mode='lines',
#                    name='Wind speed'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_wl_1['timestamp_(utc+5)'], y=df_wl_1['water_level_(m)_-_sensor_2'],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Water level 1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_wl_1['timestamp_(utc+5)'], y=df_wl_1['water_level_(m)_-_sensor_3'],
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Water level 2'))

fig.show()
```

Thank u!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Count trendline ? What do you mean. You can calculate or show trendline, it's not something you can count.

Comment: Sorry, Yes need to show trendline in plot